# jQuery Mobile: unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a an unordered list like this:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li id="1">Heading</li>
    <li id="2">Second</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is, when I add another list item:

```
<li id="3">First</li>
```

It needs to be prepended to the list item which is just below the first list item in "mylist". ie, just below 'Heading' in this case. So the final list looks like this:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li id="1">Heading</li>
    <li id="3">First</li>
    <li id="2">Second</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

---

NB: What I learned from trying to implement this is, when we append or prepend some content to an element selected with jQuery, it'll get prepended or appended to the content inside the selected element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/after/

You can use .after, or .insertAfter, for being more precise about placement in the DOM tree.

Comment: Marking this as the best answer because,
I can learn something from this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `after` method and `:first` selector:

```
$('#mylist li:first').after('<li id="3">First</li>')
```